# Set default value of field depends on other field in odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8, odoo-9

I am setting up default value of `analytics_id` in `account.move.line` by below code

```py
class account_move_line(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.move.line'
    _name = "account.move.line"

    def _get_default_account(self, cr, uid, context=None):
        obj = self.pool.get('account.move')
        value = obj.browse(cr, uid, uid)
        if  value.move_id.debit>0 or value.move_id.credit<0:
            res = self.pool.get('account.analytic.plan.instance').search(cr, uid, [('code','=','LAL')], context=context)
            return res and res[0] or False

    _defaults = {
        'analytics_id': _get_default_account,
    }
```

it is working well for me but now i want to set this default value if `debit field value is greater then zero` ***OR*** `credit field value less then zero` otherwise `analytics_id` field remain empty.

Comment: hello tahir you asking but you don't vote when some help you mmmmmmmm not good man

Comment: Sorry sir, I'll remember for next time...

Comment: Thank you  did you fix this problem!

Comment: In account move line two fields `debit` and `credit` are there with `analytics_id` field. I want to set default value something in analytics_id when debit >0 or credit <0

Comment: can you edit you question and post the code of the model and a simple exemple of what you want

Comment: ***Chrif*** I want  to get something like above code...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118081/discussion-between-charif-and-tahir-noor).

Comment: just add an else statement and you should browse with `ids` not `uid`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this type of code

```py
res = self.pool.get('account.analytic.plan.instance').search(cr, uid, [('code','=','LAL')], context=context)
if res:    
   br_analytic_plan=self.pool.get('account.analytic.plan.instance').browse(cr,uid,res[0],context=context)
   if ---your Condition---- # You can access For example. br_analytic_plan.amount > 0
       return res[0]
```

This same logic you can apply to both groups condition (it means under if and else on your current code).

Hope this helps.

Comment: In account move line two fields `debit` and `credit` are there with `analytics_id` field. I want to set default value something in analytics_id when debit >0 or credit <0