# Can i set default value by server action in odoo

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8, odoo-9

I want to set default value in `many2one` field. But i want to set it by `python code` in `server action` at `on-creation`. Problem is that, I don't know what are the rules and regulations of writing `python code` in `server action`. Is there any way to to set default value of Many2one field in server action. 
For example:
Same work is there through customized code  [Set default value of field depends on other field in odoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38524745/set-default-value-of-field-depends-on-other-field-in-odoo)

I'll be very thankful ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an automatic action for this requirement. Just create one at Settings/Technical/Automation/Automated Actions. Give it a name, the correct model you want to run it on and ofcourse set "When to run" to "On Creation".

On the second tab add a new server action. Following a simple code snippet for the server action (it's for `sale.order` and you need an `ir.config_parameter` with the given external id):

```py
object.write({'client_order_ref': 'YourRef'})
if 'A' in object.partner_id.name:
    object.write({'note': 'AAAAAAAAAA'})
else:
    object.write({'note': env.ref('mymodule.mycool_ir_config_parameter').value})
```

The example is written for Odoo V8+.

Comment: Sir I am writing this code `if object.debit==0:
    res=self.pool.get('account.analytic.account').search(cr, uid, [('name','=','Internal')], context=context)
    object.write({'account_analytic_id': res})` in server action but it is doing nothing.. please help me about it...

Comment: Sir you are setting char field value... can you please tell me how to set `many2one` field value.. pleaseeee...

Comment: You can do searches or use `env.ref()` to get other records. After that just set your many2one field with an record ID. For example (i know it isn't the best example): `object.write({'partner_id': env['res.partner'].search([], limit=1).id})` will set the first partner in database as default partner in `sale.order` creation.

Comment: Thanks sir.this code is now working well for me.. `res = self.pool.get('account.analytic.account').search(cr, uid, [('name','=','Internal')], context=context)
    object.write({'analytic_account_id': res[0]})` Thanks ... you are the best....

Comment: Sir can you please tell me how to compare `current login user id` there in python code of `server action`

Comment: if you're on Odoo V8+ you can use `env.user.id` to get the current user ID

Comment: Sir can you please tell me how to get current user name in qweb report???

Comment: That has nothing to do with this question/answer